# Forcing a click handler to recognise multiple elements

Tags: javascript

Basically, I want clicked divs to be hidden when I click a specific anchor tag inside the div. For whatever reason, this works for the first div and only this one. When I click the anchor tag in any other div, nothing happens. I don't even get a error in the console so I really just don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```js
document.querySelector(".closeWin").addEventListener("click", closeThisWin);

function closeThisWin() {
 let winToClose = this.parentElement.parentElement;
 winToClose.style.display = "none";
 console.log(winToClose);
}
```

```css
.window {
  width: 210px; height: 110px;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
  text-align: center; margin: 6px auto;
}

.css { background-color: lightpink; }

.s { font-size: 25px; padding: 40px 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="window">
  <div class="s">
    <a class="closeWin">Click Here 1</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="window css">
  <div class="s">
    <a class="closeWin">Click Here 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And Codepen: https://codepen.io/janaejpeg/pen/ExawWrm

I tried using jQuery but I didn't see any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`querySelector` -> `querySelectorAll`

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".closeWin").forEach(function(a) { a.addEventListener("click", closeThisWin)});

function closeThisWin() {
 let winToClose = this.parentElement.parentElement;
 winToClose.style.display = "none";
 console.log(winToClose);
}
```

```css
.window {
  width: 210px; height: 110px;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
  text-align: center; margin: 6px auto;
}

.css { background-color: lightpink; }

.s { font-size: 25px; padding: 40px 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="window">
  <div class="s">
    <a class="closeWin">Click Here 1</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="window css">
  <div class="s">
    <a class="closeWin">Click Here 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```